# Laravel 5.1 Polymorphic relationship Or Regular Relationship

Tags: database-design, polymorphism, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I have Three model in my code **Company, User and Employee**

```
User
 id
 name

Company
 id
 name

Employee
 employer_id // foreign key to id on company table
 employable_id
 employable_type
```

- User can have many companies as owner/director/president
- User Cannot have Any employee directly
- Company can have only one user as owner/director/president
- Company can have many employees
- Employee can have **one employer which is company**
- Employee can have many **user or company** as an employee
  -employer is always a company

  - a company as an employer,  can hire another company as an employee or a user as an employee...
  - so company can have two relation with employee table that is as an employee itself and as an employer.
  - user are not to allowed to employeed anybody directly
  - user can hire employee through a company only ..

I am not able to figure out what kind of relationship i can use here so that i can have user and company as an employee but also company as an employer.

-- Edit
I have the following table structures:

```
Employee Table ->
        employer_id' // Only company_id
        employee_person_id // user_id
        employee_company_id // Company_id as an employee
        employee_type // company or person
        name // name of company acting as employee or user full name
        email // email of company acting as employee or user email

        $table->foreign('employer_id')
            ->references('id')->on('companies')
            ->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->foreign('employee_person_id')
            ->references('id')->on('users')
            ->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->foreign('employee_company_id')
            ->references('id')->on('companies')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
```

My employee class has following methods

```
class Employee extends Model 
{
   public function employedBy()
   {
     return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\Company::class, 'employer_id');
   }

   public function employedPerson()
   {
     return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Models\User::class,   'employee_person_id');
    }

   public function employedCompany()
   {
      return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Models\Company::class, 'employee_company_id');
    }
}
```

My Company has following methods

```
class Company extends Method
{
  public function employees()
  {
    return $this->hasMany(\App\Models\Employee::class, 'employer_id');
  }

  public function employers()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Models\Employee::class, 'employee_company_id');
  }
}
```

My User has following methods

```
class User extends Method
{
  public function companies()
  {
    return $this->hasMany(\App\Models\Company::class, 'user_id');
  }

  public function employers()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Models\Employee::class, 'employee_person_id');
  }
}
```

**Ok now let me explain in steps:**

1. Company wants to hire employee ( employee can be any other company or a person)
2. Company search employee by email
3. Searched company or person added to the employee table

--Also when i query for all the employees i want to have both employed users and employed company in collection, please suggest me the way to fetch list joining users and companies through employee table--

```
// I want to write something like this
$company->getEmployees() = // to get detail list of employees and companies in one single collection
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need polymorphic for this. If your companies and users can only be employed by one employee, then their tables would contain an employee_id and they'd both **belong to** an employee as employer (**having many** users and companies); however, if they can be employed by more than one user, then you'd need to create two pivot tables and define them as in a **many to many** relationship with the employee.

So,

user and company = one to many

- a user **has many** companies
- a company **belongs to** one user

company and employee - one to many

- a company **has many** employees
- an employee **belongs to** one company

employee (as employer) and company - either one to many:

- an employee **has many** companies
- a company **has one** employee

or many to many:

- an employee **has many** companies
- a company **has many** employees

employee (as employer) and user = one to many:

- an employee **has many** users
- a user **has one** employee

or many to many:

- an employee **has many** users
- a user **has many** employees

You might need to think a little about how you name the methods for the relationship definitions in the model when the employee is in fact an employer e.g.

```
//User model

public function employer () {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Employee')
}
```

...or something.

I hope I've understood your question correctly.

Comment: thank for Timothy for your response, i understand what you saying. I have updated my question to explain bit more about my situation. Company can  hire another company or person as an employee.. but user can not hire any one. user can only own the company which can do hiring. its like real world. I also need a way to fetch all the employees hired by company in single collection whether its another company or person.